# Javascript dynamically generated select menu not seen by php in POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

The topic is not new. In fact, I wrote this code directly copying the accepted answer frmo another thread. But still my code deos not function, possibly because of slightly different circumstances.

I have a web page (generated by php) which contains a form my_form, and also another form elsewhere on the page. The function showAddRespPersonMenu below is supposed to generate a dropdown menu of employees to assign into a job, on a page which lists hundreds of jobs. (This is the reason why I create the select menu dynamically: to avoid getting the web browser stuck with 100 unnecessary hidden or visible select menus, each of them containing 100 employees to choose from.) So the user wants to modify a few of the 100 jobs, and I dynamically generate an employee menu only for the jobs which the user shows interest in, by clicking the job -- which runs the function showAddRespPersonMenu(theRespId), where the submitted theRespId is ID of the job.

The code below functions visually on the page, a select menu gets generated on the page. But it is not shown in php POST input. Executing the command var_dump($_POST) shows all static form fields and their values (of form my_form), but not the dynamically generated select menus. The divs in question are located between the  and  tags of my_form. Could the problem nevertheless be that the dynamically generated select menus do not get assigned under the form my_form, and therefore submitting my_form does not send those fields? A mystery, because in another thread a nearly identical code (apparently with one form only on the page) was accepted as functional.

```
var theSaveButtonHTML  = \'<a href="#" onclick="document.my_form.submit(); return false;"><img src="pics/save.png"></a>\';

function showAddRespPersonMenu(theRespId) {
var theDiv = document.getElementById(\'addRespPersonDiv\' + theRespId);
theDiv.innerHTML = "";
// Create and append a select menu
var selectMenu = document.createElement("select");
selectMenu.id = \'addPrimaryPersonMenu\' + theRespId;
theDiv.appendChild(selectMenu);
// Create and append options into the menu
for (var i = 0; i < personIdsArray.length; i++) {
var thisOption    = document.createElement("option");
thisOption.value = personIdsArray[i];
thisOption.text  = personNamesArray[i];
selectMenu.appendChild(thisOption);
}
document.getElementById(\'saveAddedPersonDiv\' + theRespId).innerHTML = theSaveButtonHTML;
document.getElementById(\'addUsersToResps\').value += \':\' + theRespId;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the output source-code (just a couple of lines) of both the items before the `<select>`, and the `<select>` itself? I'm guessing it's because you lack the "name"-attribute on the select...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is to add the `name` attribute to your `selectMenu` node.

`selectMenu.setAttribute('name', 'SOME_NAME');`

More information on [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

Answer (score 0):

The name parameter was missing indeed... a good point!

Unfortunately, the problem still persists after adding this code line before the appendChild command:

```
selectMenu.setAttribute(\'name\', \'add_rsp_person_primary_\' + theRespId);
```

I tried this too, with equally poor results:

```
selectMenu.name = \'add_rsp_person_primary_\' + theRespId;
```

Would be nice and clean to solve this mystery. Meanwhile, I must fix this with some chewing gum, maybe triggering an onChange function on the dynamically generated select menus, to append the user choice into a static hidden text field, which will contain as many choices to as many select menus as the user ever makes, and which php will se in POST input.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick, and functions OK... but this is a trick indeed, rather than an actual clean solution to the presented problem:

I dynamically create the select menus as innerHTML, rather than with createElement. This allows me to easily add an onChange trigger to the select menu (which might be possible with createElement too, I just don't know the syntax for it):

```
onChange="updatePrimaryPersonChoice(\' + theRespId + \', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"
```

Then the triggered function saves the user choice into a static hidden text field, which php will see in POST input:

```
function updatePrimaryPersonChoice(theRespId, thePersonId) {
// destroy from a hidden submit field any choice which the user may have done earlier
document.getElementById(\'add1stPersonsToResps\').value = document.getElementById(\'add1stPersonsToResps\').value.replace(\':\' + theRespId + \'/\', \':0/\');
// append into a hidden submit field the choice which the user has made now
document.getElementById(\'add1stPersonsToResps\').value += \':\' + theRespId + \'/\' + thePersonId;
}
```